# Clinical drug trial data analyses

Tags: multiple-regression, references, svm, clinical-trials

I am new to clinical drug trial data analyses.

The goal is to learn the analyses of clinical drug trial data, that incorporates demographic data, efficacy data and co-morbidity data at the least.

I am looking for R or python tutorials/guides that can help in self learning.

Any pointers from the experts here would be of great help and sincerely appreciated.

Thank you